# angularjs routeprovider, html5mode, and htaccess not working

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I have a single page app with a router and html5mode enabled in

```
/account/
->index.html
```

The router looks like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
    .when('/account', {
        templateUrl: 'account/views/welcome.html',
    }) //works
    .when('/account/emails', {
        templateUrl: 'account/views/email.html', 
        controller: 'emailController'
    }) //404 error
    .when('/account/wallet', {
        templateUrl: 'account/views/wallet.html',
    }) //404 error
    .when('/account/settings', {
        templateUrl: 'account/views/settings.html',
        controller: 'settingsController'
    }) //404 error
    .when('/account/logout', {
        templateUrl: 'account/views/logout.html',
    }) //404 error
});
```

Now I also have an .htaccess file in

```
/account/
->.htaccess
```

The htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On  
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d  
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

As expected, when I go to **//localhost/account/index.html** or **//localhost/account/** the URL is handled properly. Clicking through the navigation works correctly as well. However if I try to refresh the page at any of the routed links, or try to access them directly from the address bar, I get the **Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page**.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here as this seems to be pretty straight forward?

Also, if I change `RewriteRule ^ /index.html` to `RewriteRule ^ /account/index.html` instead of getting the default Apache page, I get a 404:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /account/index.html was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue quite some time ago, and there are a few pieces to check.

## index.html

In your `index.html` file's `<head>`, make sure that you have set the base href:

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

## .htaccess

Your .htaccess file looks essentially like what mine looked like when I wrote it. Here is what I used (the rewrite is probably sloppy, but it worked for me!):

```
# Enable URL rewriting/redirecting
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# if requested filename is not a file that exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# AND if requested filename is not a directory that exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# THEN rewrite the URL to be /#/PREVIOUS_URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

## AngularJS Router Config

You already have the `html5Mode` set to true, as seen in your code:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  ...
});
```

Comment: yea, my base is <base href="/june_frontend/"> but close enough for hand grenades!

Comment: using your htaccess gets me the deafult apache page still.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Apache is barfing on the # in the URL that angular uses for it's routes.
You need something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

This is going to make it skip files and head to index.html when angular requests a file.

Comment: still getting the default apache page :(

Comment: ok this is basic, but you are restarting Apache so that it picks up the changes in your htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this solved the problem

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html
</IfModule>
```